# How to recover gmail account without password?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I've changed one of the gmail passwords of one of my accounts and since forgotten it. I have tried using an old password and Google says that I have changed it.

I have acess to gmail on my phone from that account but ANYTHING I try to do requires "verification" by typing in the password I don't know (e.x. Changing recovery email or number, changing password,etc...).
The recovery email cannot be reached, as stated by Google themselves and as I stated earlier, I need to type my password in to recover it.

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en